# I am having trouble with this question including concepts on number theory and quadratic equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratics

Let *a,b* be Natural numbers where a > 1. Also *p* is a prime number. If $ax^2 + bx + c = p$ for two distinct integer values of x, then prove that $ax^2 + bx + c \neq 2p$ for any integral values of x.

So this seems to be a pretty straightforward question and I got the final expression that is $p= a (x-y)(x-z)$ where y and z are roots of equations $ax^2 + bx + c - p$, so I got p has three factors while a prime number can only have 2 factors. But I couldn’t understand what would happen if $x-y = x-z = 1$. So essentially I need to try and prove that $y \neq z$. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: "I got the final expression that is p= a (x-y)(x-z) where y and z are roots of equations"  That doesn't actually make sense as $x$ is not defined as a constant value.

Comment: " If ax2 + bx + c = p for two distinct values of x" *INTEGER* values of $x$.  If $x$ need not be an integer.....

Comment: Doesn't seem to be true $x^2 + 4x + 5$ will have $x^2+4x + 5 = 5$ will yield $x=0$ and $x=-4$ but $x=1$ will giv $x^2 + 4x + 5=2*5$.

Comment: @fleablood There is a condition $a>1$.

Comment: If $x-y = x-z = 1$ then $y = z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $m,n;m\ne n$ are integer roots to $ax^2 + bx + c = p$ then $ax^2 + bx + c-p = a(x-m)(x-n)$

Now if $ax^2 + bx + c = 2p$ then $ax^2 + bx + c -p =a(x-m)(x-n)= p$.  If $x$ is an integer and if $a > 1$ and $p$ is prime that means $a = p$ and $(x-m)(x-n) = 1$.

And $m,n$ are unequal integer then $x-m$ and $x-n$ are unequal integers.  It's easy to verify that if $b,d$ are integers and $bd=1$ then $b=d= \pm 1$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I get it now. I was really confused with the first equation that we got. I did not remember that if there are two roots to f(x)=p, then f(x) - p has the same two roots, that was foolish on my part as I was over complicating it. Thank man, appreciate it.